# Reassigning the calculated group-by column to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation

Hopefully I am asking this question the right way - thank you to the person who pointed out my mistakes earlier.

I have a dataframe (dft) of stock codes with prices, for e.g.:

```
            Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  AdjClose    StockCode
37563   2020-08-03  4.63    4.63    4.50    4.51    9602    4.51    ABA
38002   2020-08-04  4.52    4.54    4.51    4.51    4254    4.51    ABA
38374   2020-08-05  4.52    4.52    4.40    4.40    27307   4.40    ABA
38568   2020-08-06  4.41    4.58    4.41    4.58    3412    4.58    ABA
38772   2020-08-07  4.57    4.57    4.45    4.50    16260   4.50    ABA
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
77232   2021-02-15  11.06   12.76   11.06   12.66   27607862    12.66   Z1P
77632   2021-02-16  13.02   14.53   12.97   13.92   42833861    13.92   Z1P
77929   2021-02-17  13.65   13.66   11.27   11.97   29813500    11.97   Z1P
78103   2021-02-18  11.43   12.37   10.51   11.70   20602054    11.70   Z1P
78424   2021-02-19  12.10   12.59   11.87   12.35   14345435    12.35   Z1P
39741 rows × 8 columns
```

I am trying to calculate the technical indicators by stock code, which I have done here for MA_14 (Moving average, 14 time periods), i.e. split into each Stock Code and then apply the moving average calculation:

`dft.groupby(["StockCode"]).apply(lambda x: (ta.MA(x["Close"],timeperiod=14, matype=0)))`

Output:

```
StockCode       
ABA        37563          NaN
           38002          NaN
           38374          NaN
           38568          NaN
           38772          NaN
                      ...    
Z1P        77232     9.058571
           77632     9.498571
           77929     9.832143
           78103    10.148571
           78424    10.484286
Length: 39741, dtype: float64
```

The output is as per what I expected, whereby it would give back the same number of rows as the original dataframe dft.

Now I am trying to assign this MA_14 back to the original dataframe (dft).

What I have tried:

transform - but got the error message below

```
dft.groupby(["StockCode"]).transform.apply(lambda x: (ta.MA(x["Close"],timeperiod=14, matype=0)))

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Tried to directly do a row-to-row join using concat

```
grouped=dft.groupby(["StockCode"]).transform.apply(lambda x: (ta.MA(x["Close"],timeperiod=14, matype=0)))
concatenated = pd.concat([dft, grouped], axis=1)
```

which somehow gives about double the number of rows (dft = 39741 rows, concatenated = 79482) - is it something to do with indexing?

```
    Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  AdjClose    StockCode   0
37563   2020-08-03  4.63    4.63    4.50    4.51    9602.0  4.51    ABA NaN
38002   2020-08-04  4.52    4.54    4.51    4.51    4254.0  4.51    ABA NaN
38374   2020-08-05  4.52    4.52    4.40    4.40    27307.0 4.40    ABA NaN
38568   2020-08-06  4.41    4.58    4.41    4.58    3412.0  4.58    ABA NaN
38772   2020-08-07  4.57    4.57    4.45    4.50    16260.0 4.50    ABA NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
(Z1P, 77232)    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 9.058571
(Z1P, 77632)    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 9.498571
(Z1P, 77929)    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 9.832143
(Z1P, 78103)    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10.148571
(Z1P, 78424)    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10.484286
79482 rows × 9 columns
```

Tried simply assigning back to dft as such but also got an error message:

```
dft['test'] = (dft.groupby(["StockCode"]).apply(lambda x: (ta.MA(x["Close"],timeperiod=14, matype=0))))

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

How can I align the index of both 'grouped' and 'dft' so that I can perform the join correctly?

I also thought of joining using the StockCode, but that would not be correct because it would then result in each row from DFT being joined to 70K rows in grouped. Is there a way to keep both StockCode and Date in 'grouped'?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to do this. I have already searched through some threads on StackOverFlow but can't seem to find a solution that applies to this (perhaps not the right keywords being used), please do point me to the relevant posts if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the assignment to a new column within each group, as follows. The main bit is `.apply(lambda g: g.assign(...))` that assigns the right values for each group `g`. Note I do not have `ta.MA` package so I am using the standard Pandas rolling functionality, I also set `min_periods = 1` so we do not get NaNs in this example.

```
(df.reset_index()
   .groupby("StockCode",as_index = False)
   .apply(lambda g : g.assign(test = g['Close'].rolling(window = 14, min_periods = 1).mean()))
   .set_index('index')
)
```

you get

```
  index  Date          Open    High    Low    Close    Volume    AdjClose  StockCode        test
-------  ----------  ------  ------  -----  -------  --------  ----------  -----------  --------
  37563  2020-08-03    4.63    4.63   4.5      4.51      9602        4.51  ABA           4.51
  38002  2020-08-04    4.52    4.54   4.51     4.51      4254        4.51  ABA           4.51
  38374  2020-08-05    4.52    4.52   4.4      4.4      27307        4.4   ABA           4.47333
  38568  2020-08-06    4.41    4.58   4.41     4.58      3412        4.58  ABA           4.5
  38772  2020-08-07    4.57    4.57   4.45     4.5      16260        4.5   ABA           4.5
  77232  2021-02-15   11.06   12.76  11.06    12.66  27607862       12.66  Z1P          12.66
  77632  2021-02-16   13.02   14.53  12.97    13.92  42833861       13.92  Z1P          13.29
  77929  2021-02-17   13.65   13.66  11.27    11.97  29813500       11.97  Z1P          12.85
  78103  2021-02-18   11.43   12.37  10.51    11.7   20602054       11.7   Z1P          12.5625
  78424  2021-02-19   12.1    12.59  11.87    12.35  14345435       12.35  Z1P          12.52
```